# Sonata Admin Collection with sort and delete

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm trying to use a `sonata_type_collection` field for a list of ingredients associated to recipes.  Running into two issues:

1. The sortable parameter works for drag/drop re-ordering, but I can't get the items in
   the association to actually sort by that column.
2. The delete checkbox isn't working for deleting the associations.

The association is a `ManyToOne`, because the reference table has more data than just a simple reference to the Recipe table, otherwise I'd use a `ManyToMany`.

The `sortable` parameter worked nicely, making the rows draggable, however the list of ingredients isn't *sorted* by that column.  So although it saves the `position` column as it should, it doesn't actually display them in that order.

I tried to find a simple way to hook into the `PersistentCollection` in order to filter it.  I found the `matching()` function which works, but it doesn't modify the underlying collection, it just retuns back an `ArrayCollection`.  That doesn't work because I can't replace the `PersistentCollection` with an `ArrayCollection`.

Also the delete function didn't work out of the box.  I had to manually override `RecipeAdmin::preUpdate($object)` and manually remove the deleted ingredients and flush the Entity Manager.

I feel like there should be a much simpler way to do all this.

UPDATE: I discovered the `@OrderBy` annotation today which solves the sorting issue

Answer (score 3):

Always make sure to set orphanRemoval=true in your OneToMany field definition or the delete checkbox will not work.

Comment: Thanks!  I haven't been working with Symfony recently, so it might take me a little while to check this.  But thanks!